# use of variable substitution for curl in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to look up CAS registry numbers from the NIST webbook. I have a large file of chemical compounds to search. I find for example:

```
eval curl -o tmp --data-urlencode Name=barium webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi
```

works perfectly fine, but reading from a file as in

```
while read line
do 
  eval curl -o tmp --data-urlencode Name=$line webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi
done<inventory.txt
```

fails--the html output even says "The requested name (barium)" was not found. any ideas about how to proceed?

thanks!

Comment: Some problem in "inventory.txt"? In particular, \r \n problems? (execute "dos2unix" over it). Note: you do not need "eval".

Comment: wonderful, the dos2unix seems to have been the key. I knew I didn't really need "eval" but by this point I'd been trying every possible thing I could think of. But I didn't think of "dos2unix"!